# Definition of sequentially compact subset

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, limits, metric-spaces, compactness

I am reading "Beginning Functional Analysis" by Karen Saxe, and I have came upon the definition of a sequentially compact subset:
Let $(M,d)$ be a metric space. A subset $E \subset M$ is sequentially compact if every sequence of $E$ contains a convergent subsequence. Is it true that this definition lacks the additional condition that the limit of the subsequence must lie in $E$? I thought about $\mathbb{R}$ with the Euclidean distance, we can have by that definition that $(a,b)$ is sequentially compact (If a sequence is in $(a,b)$, then it is bounded so it has a convergent subsequence), sequential compactness implies compactness which implies that $(a,b)$ is closed. Am I missing something?

Comment: The limit must be in $E$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limit must be required to lie in $E$. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequentially_compact_space).

The point is that sequential compactness is an intrinsic property of a metric space (or, more generally, of a topological space). It would be adequate to define $(M,d)$ to be sequentially compact if every sequence in $M$ contains a convergent subsequence. It is then clear that the limit of this sequence must be an elements of $M$. Defining sequential compactness for subsets $E \subset M$ as Saxe obscures the fact that it is an intrisic property of the metric subpace $(E,d \mid_{E \times E})$ of $(M,d)$. It misleads the reader to think that the ambient space $(M,d)$ plays a role for the concept - which is not the case.

However, one can say that $E$ is *relatively sequentially compact in $M$*  if Saxe's condition is satisfied. Here the limits of convergent subsequences (there may be many such sequences!) are not required to lie in $E$. But note that they will lie in $\overline E$.

See [Definition for "relatively sequentially compact"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1585584).